# How is this NYT Mapbox map rendered?

Tags: leaflet, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

The map below is a high resolution county Mapbox map, with dynamically changing data. When trying to render the same high resolution county map with other tools, a lot of processing power is required. Why is this different?

Additionally, I believe they are using a custom tileset to render the county shapes, but then how is the data passed into the visualization? Any insight here would be appreciated. [NYT Map Link](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-risk-map.html)

[image: https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/us/covid-risk-map.html]

Comment: You seem to be asking for the architectural design of mapbox-gl-js v1, which is [still kinda unknown/undocumented](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/blob/main/ARCHITECTURE.md).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you want to know is in their [main.js script](https://static01.nyt.com/newsgraphics/2021/01/20/2021-01-county-risk-map/9b80045dd7c8dd59894265efad1445b5720e6509/build/js/main.js)

They do not use leaflet but mapbox-gl-js `sdkVersion:"2.0.1"`

They create a map with their own style

```js
map$1 = new mapboxGl.Map({
        container: $wrap,
        style: 'mapbox://styles/nytgraphics/cjnxfd2cy57nq2rqj8o3d7sl2',
        scrollZoom: false,
        boxZoom: false,
        maxZoom: 10
    });
```

Then they create their fill layers based on the sources they load

```js
function addSources() {
    Object.keys(tilesets).forEach((name) => {
        map$1.addSource(name, {
            type: 'vector',
            url: `mapbox://${tilesets[name]}`,
            promoteId: 'geoid'
        });
    });

    map$1.on('sourcedata', () => {
        addLayers();
    });
}
...
...

map$1.addLayer({
        id: 'counties',
        type: 'fill',
        source: 'counties',
        'source-layer': 'USA_Counties_With_RI',
        paint: {
            'fill-color': [
                'case',
                ['has', ['get', 'geoid'], ['literal', colorLookup]],
                ['get', ['get', 'geoid'], ['literal', colorLookup]],
                '#cccccc'
            ],
        }
    });
```